# Clojure - require all test namespaces within the REPL?

Tags: clojure

Say I have the following namespaces:

```
(ns testsuite.bar ...)
```

and

```
(ns testsuite.foo ...)
```

Is there a way to require/use all the namespaces within `testsuite` ?

Something like:

```
(use 'testsuite.*)
(run-all-tests)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this isn't supported. You must use/require individually. However, `(run-all-tests)` doesn't require any test namespaces to be used or required, because it will automatically run all tests from all available (loaded) namespaces.